# Which templating engine can I use with both JS and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, template-engine, templating

I'm looking for a simple Template engine that works both on client side with JS ánd on server side with PHP.

That means I want to be able to use **the same template definition** for both use cases.

Do you know any templating engines that have official implementations in both JS and PHP?

Comment: I'm asking myself same question nowadays, and looks to me more about existence of working implementations and their status than a recommendation, the problem is obvious, edit templates only once, should be a common problem so why there are so few (or not production ready) solutions? what are best practices to share templates? or if it is a evil thing, why?

Comment: See [Contemplate engine](https://github.com/foo123/Contemplate) which was specificaly designed to be isomorphic and be used in js/node/php/python. It is also both extremely fast and extremely flexible supporting template inherittance and many features (similar to twig/swig) (ps I am the author)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you like **JS->PHP priority** :) then you have this two jquery-tmpl compatible template renderer for PHP backend

1. https://github.com/abackstrom/jquery-tmpl-php
2. https://github.com/xyu/jquery-tmpl-php

If you prefer more **PHP->JS priority** :) then you can try this Javascript implementation of popular PHP templating Smarty

1. http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/

Or you can try something more neutral like:

1. Mustache http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: This is what I call a good answer. Short, accurate and explanatory. Cheers

Answer (score 17):

You have a new option to compile templates for both PHP and JS using Twig + Twig.js

- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/
- https://github.com/schmittjoh/twig.js

Comment: thanks :) i'll have a look at it

Comment: have you used TwigJS? it looks to me as if it doesn't have any of the standard filters or functions actually implemented (?)

Comment: There's also another Twig implementation in JS here: https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js/ that's more full-featured.

Comment: AFAIK, all JS versions of Twig are but subsets of the PHP version of Twig and none of them are official implementations.

Answer (score 16):

Do you mean something like [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)?

Comment: That's it, i saw this some days ago, but i neither remembered where i saw it nor what it was called :) Thanks! (I have to wait 4 more minutes to accept your answer).

Comment: Depending on your needs, Mustache may be too simple - if you're hoping to e.g. `json_encode()` your view-models and render your views both client- and server-side, you may find that simple things like formatting numbers or dates still requires you to write both client and server functions, whereas Twig and Twig.js may provide a lot more of that stuff out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

Use **[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)**!

AFAIK, Mustache is the only template engine that has **official implementations** in  both PHP and JS... along with two dozen programming/scripting languages.

- Twig does have a JS version, but that's incomplete and AFAIK unofficial.
- Smarty does have a JS version, but it's also an unofficial port... and Smarty is getting a bit outdated.