# Template engine for PHP + JS but

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, template-engine, zend-view

I'm building a web app that relies fairly heavily on Ajax for its interactivity, and I want to get around the problem of having two versions of my HTML templates, to keep things DRY.

I came across a question here, [template engine both for JS and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004060/template-engine-both-for-js-and-php), which came up with a good answer, [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). Then I remembered all the stuff I wouldn't be able to do, like Zend_View_Helpers, and other PHP reliant stuff.

My question is, are there any better solutions? Perhaps that would allow me to use Zend_View (or similar to output to a templating language), which would allow me the flexibility of PHP and its libraries, but the DRYness of a template language.

That, or another solution entirely that I haven't thought of. I'm sure this sort of thing has been done many times before, so are there any best practices (or bad ones).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I am not entirely sure what you are attempting to do how about using [the Twig project](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). You can pass objects into the template and access its properties and methods:

> For convenience sake foo.bar does the following things on the PHP layer:
>
> - check if foo is an array and bar a valid element;
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that bar is a valid property;
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that bar is a valid method (even if bar is the constructor - use __construct() instead);
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that getBar is a valid method;
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that isBar is a valid method;
> - if not, return a null value.
>
> foo['bar'] on the other hand only works with PHP arrays:
>
> - check if foo is an array and bar a valid element;
> - if not, return a null value.

There is also a [JS port of the Twig templating language](https://github.com/fadrizul/twigjs).

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, yeah. I'll look into that. I guess what I'm looking for is the ability to have 2 stage templates. PHP in the first, which outputs a language-agnostic template, in Twig, Mustache, etc.. Maybe that's a crazy idea, maybe it's not what I want at all?